# How to put the burger icon in a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I want to use burger icon i.e.

[image]

Basically I don't know how to put the burger icon in a `UIBarButtonItem`, and only exists in *System item* some icons and not exists what I want.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `UIBarButtonItem`? There's an obvious `init` for using your own image.

Comment: look around then post the question.https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem

Comment: it could be useful for you http://www.jobinandjismi.com/how-to-change-uibarbuttonitem-image-programmatically-in-swift/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `UIBarButtonItem` constructor `init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: Any?, action: Selector?)`

an example usage would be:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "burger_icon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.someMethod))
```

In this example "burger_icon" is the name of the image asset in your project and `self.someMethod` is the method that is called when this button is tapped.

For more information on the `UIBarButtonItem` class you can look at the Apple documentation for the class. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage(systemName: "line.horizontal.3"), for: .normal)
```

To look for system icons in Xcode, Command-Shift-L and click the star.[image]

Comment: Given how old the question is, you should mention that your answer applies to iOS 13.0 and later. But also note that "line.horizontal.3" was deprecated in iOS 15.0 and replaced with "line.3.horizontal". This can be seen in the "SF Symbols" macOS app provided by Apple.